azure.dataprotection_backupvaults.backup_health_event available not showing up in Azure Monitor for Azure disk backups
I have multiple Azure disks and AKS clusters backing up to an Azure Backup Vault.
We are trying to view health event metrics (azure.dataprotection_backupvaults.backup_health_event) in Azure Monitor for those Azure disks. We are trying to view the metrics in Backup Center metrics tab.
We can see that metric for AKS backups but not for Azure Disks.
Is this expected behavior? Are we doing something incorrect?

Kindly read this to cross check if your setup is inline as per the suggestion- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/metrics-overview#supported-built-in-metrics

Health event metrics for AKS backups are fully supported, and hence you are able to view them. However, for Azure Disk backups, Azure might not yet support or expose the backup_health_event metric in the same way, which is why you are not seeing these metrics in Azure Monitor.
To view the current supported metrics for Azure Disks run
az monitor diagnostic-settings categories list \
  --resource /subscriptions/abcd-efgh-ijk-lmnop-qrst/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/arkbackupvault

You will see that the supported categories are as follows-

CoreAzureBackup
AddonAzureBackupJobs
AddonAzureBackupPolicy
AddonAzureBackupProtectedInstance

For metrics it's just Health. There is no backup_health_event metric.

Therefore, with the right metrics your corrected diagnostic settings should be-
az monitor diagnostic-settings create \
  --name backupvaultdiagnostic \
  --resource /subscriptions/abcd-efgh-ijk-lmno-pqrst/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/arkbackupvault \
  --metrics '[{"category": "Health", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": {"days": 0, "enabled": false}}]' \
  --logs '[{"category": "CoreAzureBackup", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": {"days": 0, "enabled": false}}, {"category": "AddonAzureBackupJobs", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": {"days": 0, "enabled": false}}, {"category": "AddonAzureBackupPolicy", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": {"days": 0, "enabled": false}}, {"category": "AddonAzureBackupProtectedInstance", "enabled": true, "retentionPolicy": {"days": 0, "enabled": false}}]' \
  --workspace /subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmno-pqrst/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/ArkoLogworkspace


This will create diagnostic settings successfully for your Backup Vault, and the metrics and logs will now get routed to your Log Analytics workspace
References:

Monitor the health of your backups using Azure Backup Metrics (preview)

